# Como checar se usuário saiu da janela

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber uma maneira de checar se o usuário saiu da janela da minha página com Javascript, por exemplo, caso ele troque de aba (para pesquisar algo no Google por exemplo) o script troca o título da janela para outro título que eu definir..

Comment: probleminha chato esse, já quebrei bastante a cabeça com isso e cheguei a conclusão que não existe uma maneira confiável crossbrowser de resolver. a coisa fica mais chata ainda quando tem iframe na jogada. Quando o usuário interage com o iframe, o browser chama o teu window.blur...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Penso que pode usar o evento `blur`

Exemplo usando javascript simples:

```
window.addEventListener('blur', function(){
    // correr codigo aqui
});
```

No exemplo para além de disparar o evento na mudança de janela, quando faz focus na barra de endereço ele dispara também.

**EDIT:**

Acrescento mais info depois de uma boa pergunta do [@JoãoParaná](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8600/como-checar-se-usuario-saiu-da-janela/8601?noredirect=1#comment14666_8601):

No Safari/IOS o evento `blur` não dispara. Nesse caso deve ser usado o `pagehide`. 
Pode ter de usar-se os dois caso necessário:

```
window.addEventListener('blur', correrEstaFuncao);
window.addEventListener('pagehide', correrEstaFuncao);
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8qgs5/show/)

Comment: Oi @sergio, o exemplo não funcionou no Safari do iPad com iOS 7. Não testei em outras versões.

Comment: @JoãoParaná, boa questão. Juntei mais info à resposta.

Answer (score 2):

A nova api HTML5 [**`Page Visibility API`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API) faz justamente o que você está pedindo:

```
if(document.hidden !== undefined){
    document.addEventListener("visibilityChange", acao, false);   
}

function acao(){
    console.log("O estado da janela mudou!");
}
```

Exemplo: [**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/LhEEE/1/)

Answer (score 1):

A algum tempo eu procurei por um script que fazia justamente isso.

Ele adiciona *listeners* para vários tipos de browsers. Chamando a função `functionHidden` quando a página perder o "foco". E `functionVisible` quando a página voltar a ter "foco".

```
(function () {
    var hidden = "hidden";
    if (hidden in document) document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onchange);
    else if ((hidden = "mozHidden") in document) document.addEventListener("mozvisibilitychange", onchange);
    else if ((hidden = "webkitHidden") in document) document.addEventListener("webkitvisibilitychange", onchange);
    else if ((hidden = "msHidden") in document) document.addEventListener("msvisibilitychange", onchange);
    else if ('onfocusin' in document) document.onfocusin = document.onfocusout = onchange;
    else window.onpageshow = window.onpagehide = window.onfocus = window.onblur = onchange;

    function onchange(evt) {
        var evtMap = {
            focus: true,
            focusin: true,
            pageshow: true,
            blur: false,
            focusout: false,
            pagehide: false
        };

        evt = evt || window.event;
        if (evt.type in evtMap) evtMap[evt.type] ? functionVisible() : functionHidden();
        else this[hidden] ? functionHidden() : functionVisible();
    }

    function functionVisible() {
        console.log('Visible');
    }

    function functionHidden() {
        console.log('Hidden');
    }
})();
```

Esse script mapeia os eventos de quase todos os browsers.

Você poderá testa-lo no **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LEXCool/L356U/)** olhando o console.