# Evento quando usuário fechou a aba/pagina

Tags: javascript, html

Estou precisando saber como **executar uma função** no mesmo instante que eu **fechar a pagina**, por exemplo quero enviar um alerta para o usuário assim que ele sair

Pesquisando aqui no site eu encontrei esse código:

```
window.onunload = function() {
    alert('Valeu, falow.');
    //Seu código aqui
}
```

Só que eu não consegui implementar ele no meu projeto!

Espero que vocês possam me ajudar!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve usar isso:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){

    return "Hello"

}
```

> A window’s onbeforeunload property may be set to a function that returns a string that is shown to the user in a dialog box to confirm that the user wants to navigate away. This was intended to prevent users from losing data during navigation. Unfortunately, it is often used to scam users.

Aqui diz, basicamente, que você tem que retornar uma string para o usuário, para que ele possa decidir se ele vai sair ou não. **mas...**

> Starting in Chrome 51, a custom string will no longer be shown to the user. Chrome will still show a dialog to prevent users from losing data, but it's contents will be set by the browser instead of the web page.

A partir do google Chrome 51, retornar strings não é mais permitido, ou seja, você até pode, mas o chrome exibirá a mensagem padrão deles.

## Explicando o fechamento da página

```
//MEUS ARQUIVOS
/
/index.js
/fechou.php   #SERÁ EXECUTADO QUANDO A APLICAÇÃO SAIR DA MEMORIA RAM/CPU
/index.html
```

---

```
//fechou.php
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];

file_put_contents("pessoas_que_fecharam.txt", $name);
```

---

```
//index.js
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return "Não será apresentado na tela";
}
window.onunload = function () {
    //essa evento é executado depois de window.onbeforeunload.
    //Quando a página é fechada, o navegador executa isso aqui(POST)
    //quando o post é executado, o navegador tira tudo da memoria RAM
    //e processador
    $.post("fechou.php", {name: "MARCELO"});
}
```

---

```
<!--INDEX.HTML-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Primeiro

Quando o usuário clica para fechar a página/tab, `window.onbeforeunload` é executado e então, aparece uma mensagem, perguntando se o usuário quer sair ou não. Essa é minha `window.onbeforeunload`

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return "Não será apresentado na tela";
}
```

### Segundo

Quando o usuário decide deixar a página, `window.onunload` é executado.

```
window.onunload = function () {
    //essa evento é executado depois de window.onbeforeunload.
    //Quando a página é fechada, o navegador executa isso aqui(POST)
    //quando o post é executado, o navegador tira tudo da memoria RAM
    //e processador
    $.post("fechou.php", {name: "MARCELO"});
}
```

quando `window.onunload` for executado/terminado, o navegador tira tudo da memória. E eu deveria ter um arquivo chamado `pessoas_quechamaram.txt` com o nome `MARCELO` dentro.

---

Fontes:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/chrome-51-deprecations#remove_custom_messages_in_onbeforeunload_dialogs

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13443562/7173478

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload

Comment: É quase isso, porém nesse ele dá aquele aviso de quando a pessoa sai do site, tem como fazer sem esse aviso ?

Comment: Este codigo que você mostrou eu também tinha encontrado nas minhas pesquisas

Comment: @GustavoBessa Voce quer remover a mensagem padrão do chrome, quando o usuário fecha a aba do seu site ?

Comment: Sim, eu quero enviar pro servidor que a pessoa saiu do site

Comment: Eu tentei usar a função aqui, mas não é possível eu mostrar um alert na função

    window.onbeforeunload = fecharJanela  

    function fecharJanela(){  
  alert("Você realmente deseja fechar a janela?");
     return 'oi'; 
    }

Comment: Sim, não é possível, o chrome faz isso automaticamente para voce, porém mostrando a mensagem deles.

Comment: Consegui achar algo proximo do que eu queria, obrigado pela ajuda... https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8600/como-checar-se-usu%C3%A1rio-saiu-da-janela

Comment: Vou te explicar direito espera.

Comment: @GustavoBessa tá lá

Comment: @GustavoBessa retire o que eu disse, eu tinha dito que voce precisava a mensagem executar para que desse tempo da `função` ser executada, isso foi um engano, estudei melhor e vi que `window.onunload` é executado mesmo se a página já está fechada.

Comment: Agora eu entendi, agora eu saquei, agora todas as peças se encaixaram, obrigado cara você salvou o meu projeto

Comment: @GustavoBessa infelizmente não poderá mostrar a mensagem, mas feliz por ter ajudado.