# Executar função ao fechar a janela

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando executar a função abaixo de forma que quando o usuário fechar a pagina, um alerta aparecerá perguntando se deseja salvar antes de sair, ao clicar em `OK`, o progresso do formulário será salvo no `localStorage` e ao clicar em `Cancelar`, a janela será fechada como o usuário solicitou, porém não está funcionando de maneira alguma, o que está errado? É possível fazer isso?

**Código:**

```html
<form id="msform">
<input id="um" /><br>
<input id="dois" />
</form>
```

```js
window.onbeforeunload = saida;

function saida(){

   var sair = confirm("Deseja salvar antes de sair?");

   if (sair == true) {
      [].forEach.call(document.querySelector('#msform').elements, function(el) {
         localStorage.setItem(el.id, el.value);
      });
   } else {
      window.close();
   }

}
```

Comment: Leia [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/275577/evento-quando-usu%C3%A1rio-fechou-a-aba-pagina/275578#275578) resposta que eu tinha feito há um tempo, vai entender como o `onbeforeunload` funciona.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Evento quando usuário fechou a aba/pagina](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/275577/evento-quando-usu%c3%a1rio-fechou-a-aba-pagina)

Answer (score 0):

Coloquei alguns `alerts` em seu código, veja o que exibe em cada caso, basicamente você vai debugar o código.

```
window.onbeforeunload = saida;

function saida(){
 alert ('ok1')
   var sair = confirm("Deseja salvar antes de sair?");

   if (sair == true) {
     alert ('ok2')
[].forEach.call(document.querySelector('#msform').elements, function(el) {
         localStorage.setItem(el.id, el.value);
      });
   } else {
      alert ('ok3')
      window.close();
   }

}
```

Comment: Continua não funcionando